# Push and Pop without indexer or array

Tags: c#, .net

This code seems fairly simple,yet I can't grasp the simple fact that how is an array less property  (next and data) storing or adding 3 different numbers? Can anyone help me on this?.No storing instances in an array or the data so how is this working?

Thanks

```
class Program
{
    public class Stack<T>
    {
        Entry _top; 
        public void Push(T data)
        {
            _top = new Entry(_top,data);
            
        }   
        public T Pop()
        {
            if(_top==null){throw new InvalidOperationException();}
            T result =_top.Data ; 
            _top=_top.Next;
            return result ; 
        }
        

    public class Entry 
    {
        public Entry Next{get;set ;}
        public T Data{get;set;}

        public Entry(Entry next,T data)
        {
            Next = next  ; 
            Data = data ; 
        }
    }
    }

     
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var mystack= new Stack<int>() ;
        mystack.Push(100);
        mystack.Push(50);
        mystack.Push(45);
        System.Console.WriteLine(mystack.Pop());
        System.Console.WriteLine(mystack.Pop());
        System.Console.WriteLine(mystack.Pop());

    Console.ReadKey();
               
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Look up the data structure concept called "linked list".

Comment: it will throw null reference exception on this line `Console.WriteLine(_top.Next);`

Comment: There is a simple C# implementation of a linked list based stack at the bottom of this page: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-a-stack-using-singly-linked-list/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have here a recursive stack definition: each instance of an Entry points also to another instance of the SAME Entry type. That way you can define structures containing several elements (tree, linked list, etc.) without using explicitely an array.

Concretely with your example:

1.) First push: the _top element of the stack will be set to new Entry (lets call it Entry1) having the property Next set to null and Entry1 Data set to your added object (lets call it Data1 = 100)

2.) Second push: the _top element of the stack will be set to new Entry (lets call it Entry2) having the property Next set to Entry1 and Data set to your currently added object (call it Data2 = 50)

3.)Third push: the _top element of the stack will be set to new Entry (lets call it Entry3) having the property Next set to Entry2 and Data set to your currently added object (call it Data3 = 45)

=> You have after these three steps a stack having as _top Entry3 pointing (through Next) to Entry2 poitning (through Next) to Entry1.

Comment: I would define it more specifically as a stack based on a singly-linked list, as opposed to being based off an array (generally the more efficient implementation